# AWS - I want to route traffic from one VPC to another, but I want all traffic INTO that VPC to share an IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, gateway, vpc-peering

Due to a very complicated situation that I can't really get into, we have a VPC that has access to a certain server via a direct connection.

This server requires that we whitelist an IP to access it. We don't *exactly* have a limit on how many IPs can be whitelisted but we have a practical limitation that for whatever reason it takes a very long time to get an IP whitelisted.

What we want to do is to have some way to route traffic to that server, but that traffic will all be coming from the same IP address, and we want to do this without routing the traffic through an EC2 server. We already have it set up to do that and are encountering limitations with this approach.

I had an idea that maybe I can setup a separate VPC, create a NAT Gateway in that VPC with a particular IP address, route traffic through that into the VPC we need so that we can connect to the server and it'll all come in as that Gateway's IP Address. Then I went and tried to set it up and I can't seem to figure out how it will work. It's possible I was wrong and that I can't do it this way.

Is there an easy way to accomplish what I want to do here? We don't necessarily NEED to have the traffic coming from a different VPC, if there's a way to do this within the VPC that'll work too.

Comment: You've described a need for a proxy, and said you're finding problems with the proxy you set up. What problems are you having? AWS has some documentation which might get you started on using NAT Gateway as a proxy here, it uses VPN but you can probably modify the approach to use DirectConnect https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-scenarios.html#private-nat-allowed-range